# Android: Error in Cursor.getColumnNames on froyo

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

In versions 1.6 and 2.1 android getColumnNames function returns me an array of field names + aliases? Why?

for example.

```
SELECT c.idCliente, c.nombre,COUNT(cab.idcomprobante) AS cbtes FROM Customers AS c LEFT JOIN AS cab Headers ON c.idCliente=cab.idCliente
```

with this query getColumnNames function () returns an array:

```
"c.idCliente"
"c.nombre"
"cbtes"
```

Why the alias is in front?

in version 2.2 of android, the same array have the following values.

```
"idCliente"
"nombre"
"cbtes"
```

this is the right thing ... but obviously throw an error and can not find the name of the column in the array.

wonder if the solution to this problem is the following:

```
SELECT c.idCliente AS idCliente,c.nombre AS nombre,COUNT(cab.idcomprobante) AS cbtes FROM Clientes AS c LEFT JOIN Cabeceras AS cab ON c.idCliente = cab.idCliente
```

with the "AS" in every field?

Answer (score 0):

my friend "AS" not support to squlite
you wont to both table comen data that to try to compare single single query to compare that one possible

Comment: sorry, but I've solved it by placing "AS" in each field, "AS" works in sqlite.